# Permisson requirement for Song usage in movies

Tags: production, soundtrack, copyright

When songs are used in movies, in what circumstances it is required to get permission or is it always required? For example,
If a song is played in the background and used as a soundtrack for the movie/TV show, I guess it is definitely required to obtain permission from the owners. But let's say if the song is used indirectly such as playing on radio or playing on TV, is it still required to get permission. Also let's say a character from the movie or TV show is shown singing that song, is it still required to get permission in such cases?

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate?): http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13975/49.

Comment: Yes, permission is ALWAYS required unless its public domain.