# How music piece usage rights work in TV vs YouTube?

Tags: soundtrack, copyright, youtube

I have seen many episodes of *[The Kapil Sharma Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kapil_Sharma_Show)* on Sony's YouTube channel and noticed that whenever a song comes, they just mute it and replace it with some generic music piece. But why? When the same episode comes on TV, they use the same song freely. Even in most of the time song is from the film which is promoted by the episode guest, then why it can't be used in YouTube? How does music usage rights work in YouTube and how it's different from television broadcast?

I have noticed it in few other shows too like [Comedy Circus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comedy_Circus) where they mute the entry song of the contestant.

Comment: I didn't know this as I used to watch 'em on TV.

Comment: TV usage rights are contracted **by country**...Youtube is global.

Comment: Related - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13975/what-are-the-rules-regarding-usage-of-non-featured-songs-in-films/15449#15449

Comment: TV usage is usually very "liberal", you can see on various TV reports, when they use current chart hits in tha background. Which you can't do in Movies or on Youtube without gettingthe rights to do so.And as mentionned before, global rights are expensive.

Comment: You can take a look at this: http://tubularinsights.com/copyrighted-music-in-video/

Comment: this is unconfirmed but i do recall that youtube's Content ID system can id songs and notify the copyright owners which could result in a strike against a channel or lose of monetization (varying from a portion to all of it going to the copyright ownser)